# ElasticSearch 8.3.3, custom analyzer "not configured in mappings"

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use `elasticdump` to load a mapping to elastic search. The complete file is shown bellow. Looking to the documentation, it "should work". Nevertheless, I get the error:

```
Fri, 19 Aug 2022 21:04:48 GMT | Error Emitted => {"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping: analyzer [my_lc_analyzer] has not been configured in mappings"}],
"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping: analyzer [my_lc_analyzer] has not been configured in mappings","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"analyzer [my_lc_analyzer] has not been configured in mappings"}}
```

The complete mappings file is:

```
{
    "ngrams": {
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "my_lc_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase",
                            "asciifolding"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "canvas_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "document_id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                },
                "text": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "analyzer": "my_lc_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found some examples in the web, where the `settings` key has an extra level, `index`, inside it. I tried that too, with no luck.

I suppose I am missing some stupid detail, but not finding it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe key "ngram" be the problem.

```
PUT my-index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_lc_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "canvas_id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "document_id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_lc_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The key is just used by elasticdump to know the index name. It *should* not be the problem. But I will try the direct PUT just in case...

Answer (score 0):

While I posted in the original question, it was probably disregarded by most readers. I am using `elasticdump` for dumping and restoring the database.

My main mistake was to edit the dump produced by `elasticdump` and adding the `settings` section, to describe the analyzer. And I did this without reading the `elasticdump` documentation, and it made sense in my head to have a single post to create the index and respective settings.

Nevertheless, that is not the case. `elasticdump` distinguishes between `data`, `settings`, `analyzers`, `mappings` and others. And thus, an export of type `analyzers` must be done, and that is what must be supplied during import (with the specific `analyzers` type).

While I think `elasticdump` might have a cleaner interface, I solved my issue, exporting the `analyzers`, and importing it before the `mappings` info.